# PowerShell RegEx to get value of registry key from .reg file (reg export)

Tags: regex, powershell, registry

I have a PowerShell script which should compare two .reg files (reg export files). I want to provide a registry key name and compare the value of this key in those files.
My problem is with the regex to only choose the value of the specific key...

The Problem is that the output is not only the value of the key I provide but also all the following lines in the regfile... (that's where I fail with the RegEx)

content of the regfile (example to test):

```
"DWORD"=dword:fefefeff
"String"="agnhqorewthosdgfalsfalsbvoweirnfapjfpaqwogfjasgj"
"DWORD2"=dword:fefefefe
"qword"=hex(b):fa,ad,df,fa,ad,df,fa,ad
```

PowerShell Code:

```
$RegKeyName = "DWORD2"
$regex = ('"{0}"=(.*(?:(?!\n"[^\n"]+"=)\n.*)*)' -f [RegEx]::Escape($RegKeyName))
[regex]::Matches($regfilecontent ,$regex) | foreach { $_.groups[1].value }
```

expected result for example $RegKeyName=DWORD2 should be:
dword:fefefefe

actual result is:
dword:fefefefe
"qword"=hex(b):fa,ad,df,fa,ad,df,fa,ad

Comment: What I have to mention is: if the content I'm looking through is a string of basetype "System.Object" the code works as expected. but if i get the content from a regfile and it is a Object[] of basetype System.array the result is as described above

Answer (score 1):

OK it was pretty simple, I just had to convert the content first to a proper string, afterwards the result was as expected:

```
$regfilecontent = $regfilecontent |Out-String
```